# Angular2 : Error trying to diff 'true' with ngDoCheck()

Tags: typescript, angular

## Introduction

Hi, I'm kinda new to Angular2, and to Typescript (and I'm also new to StackOverflow.com), and I was wondering if you could help me with the following issue :
I've made work my own collapse animation on a button using **ngOnChanges()** on the button click. Now, my aim is to make it so when the user clicks anywhere on the page (outside my displayed menu or elsewhere than my button managing the menu), the menu collapses to be hidden.

To do that, I want my collapse.animation.ts detect with ngDoCheck() when the collapse property from my header.component.ts is updated with the clickOutsideEvent().

I've been trying to make an event such as `(blur)="onBlur()"` or `(blur)="expression"` work, but unfortunately it was not working properly because of the focus on the single html element. Or I did not manage to make it properly...

This is the exception I'm getting : 
angular2.dev.js:23730 **EXCEPTION: Error trying to diff 'true' in [isCollapsed in HeaderComponent@16:59]**

Sorry if the post is too long or if it's not clear enough, any help will be greatly appreciated.

### The code I'm working on

**collapse.animation.ts** : It's in this file that I manage the collapse animation, and that I try to detect the collapse change and hide / show accordingly.

```
import {Directive, DoCheck, KeyValueDiffers , OnChanges, ElementRef, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import {AnimationBuilder} from 'angular2/src/animate/animation_builder';
import {CssAnimationBuilder} from 'angular2/src/animate/css_animation_builder';

@Directive({
    selector: '[collapse]',
    host: {
        '[attr.aria-expanded]': '!collapse',
        '[attr.aria-hidden]': 'collapse'
    }
})

export class Collapse implements OnChanges, DoCheck {
    @Input() duration: number = 200;            // Vitesse de l'animation en ms. (750 = 0.75 sec)
    @Input() collapse: any;                     // Booléen définissant l'état collapse ou non

    private _animation: CssAnimationBuilder;    // Animation CSS
    differ: any;                                // Tracker de propriété / attribut.

constructor(private _animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder, private _element: ElementRef, private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    // Initialisation de l'animation css.
    this._animation = _animationBuilder.css();
    // Initialisation du tracker
    this.differ = differs.find({}).create(null);
}

// trying to make this work...
ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.collapse);

    if (changes) {
        changes.forEachChangedItem((elt) => {
            if (elt.key === 'isCollapsed') {
                this.show();
            }
            else {
                this.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}

// Manage property collapse
// This works when I click on my button
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.collapse) {
        if (this.collapse) {
            this.hide();
        } else {
            this.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**header.component.ts** : This is my header component containing my menu

```
import { Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import { Collapse } from './../../css/animations/collapse.animation';
import { ClickOutside } from './../directives/clickOutside.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'headerComponent',
    templateUrl: 'app/master/header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/master/header.component.css', 'app/master/menuNavigation.component.css', 'css/animations/collapse.animation.css'],
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        Collapse,
        ClickOutside
    ],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ],
})

export class HeaderComponent {
    @Input() collapse: boolean = false;

    private headerMenuClass: string = "header_menu";

    // clickOutside linked method
    handleClickOutside(className) {
        // I'm detecting the "click" on my button linked to my menu with it's class "header_menu". No need to collapse the menu when I click on my button.
        let FirstClassName: string = className.split(" ")[0];
        if (FirstClassName != this.headerMenuClass) {
            console.log(this.collapse);
            // Trying to make my collapse.animation.ts detect this !!
            this.collapse = !this.collapse;
        }
    }
}
```

**header.component.html** : The HTML template of my component

```
<div id="top_bar" class="top_bar">


    <!-- This is the button that shows the menu -->

    <button type="button" class="header_menu nav_icon root_navitem" id="btn_menu_switch" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
        <img class="header_menu" src="css/App_Themes/VAL/48x48/m_bars.png" alt="" />
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="nav_icon" id="btn_home" [routerLink]="['Accueil']">
        <img src="css/App_Themes/VAL/48x48/m_home.png" alt="" />
    </button>
</div>

<!-- This is the menu I'm trying to collapse at will -->

<div id="left_bar" tabindex="-1" class="left_bar collapse" [collapse]="isCollapsed"
     (clickOutside)="handleClickOutside( $event.target.className )">

    <div id="left_bar_menu" class="left_bar_menu">
        <button type="button" class="left_bar_icon" id="btn_left_histo">
            <img src="css/App_Themes/VAL/48x48/m_history.png" alt="" />
        </button>
        <hr class="sep" />
        <button type="button" class="left_bar_icon" id="btn_left_board" [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">
            <img src="css/App_Themes/VAL/48x48/m_board.png" alt="" />
        </button>
        <hr class="sep" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**clickOutside.directive.ts** : This file allows me to detect when I click outside a component and get some information. I believe this is not a clean way to manage my issue, but I'll work on that later.

```
import {Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from 'angular2/core';

// Variable globale à la classe
var localEvent: any = null;

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]',
    host: {
        "(click)": "trackEvent( $event )",
        "(document: click)": "compareEvent( $event )"
    }
})

export class ClickOutside {
    @Output() clickOutside;

    constructor() {
        this.clickOutside = new EventEmitter();
    }

    // If the event at the document root is the same reference as the
    // event at the target, it means that the event originated from
    // within the target and bubbled all the way to the root. As such,
    // if the event at the document root does NOT MATCH the last known
    // event at the target, the event must have originated from
    // outside of the target.
    compareEvent(event) {
        if (event !== localEvent) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
        localEvent = null;
    }

    // I track the click event on the bound target.
    trackEvent(event) {
        // When the user clicks inside the bound target, we need to start
        // tracking the event as it bubbles up the DOM tree. This way,
        // when a click event hits the document root, we can determine if
        // the event originated from within the target.
        localEvent = event;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `ngDoCheck` is what you need here. As a matter of fact, Angular2 detects changes by value for primitive types and by references for object but doesn't detect changes in arrays or objects.

For this case (not the default detection), you need to use the `ngDoCheck` to implement a custom way to detect these updates. It relies on classes `KeyValueDiffers` for objects and `IterableDiffers` for arrays. But you can't use the `KeyValueDiffers` class with a boolean value. It doesn't make for this.

In your case you can rely on the default detection for the `collapse` input property. When its value is updated the `ngOnChanges` is called and you trigger your own processing.

That being said, if you want to implement the collapse feature and trigger from anywhere in your application, you should consider to use a shared service, for example a `MenuService`. You could put a boolean property in it for the state of the menu with an observable / subject to notify when it's updated:

```
export class MenuService {
  collapse:boolean;
  collapse$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  toggleMenu() {
    this.collapse = !this.collapse;
    this.collapse$.next(this.collapse);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to put it when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ MenuService ]);
```

And don't define it again within the `providers` attribute of components.

Then you can inject it into your components / directives to either update the state or be notified when the state is updated.

Here is a sample in your directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[collapse]',
  host: {
    '[attr.aria-expanded]': '!collapse',
    '[attr.aria-hidden]': 'collapse'
  }
})
export class Collapse implements OnChanges {
  @Input() duration: number = 200;
  @Input() collapse: any;

  private _animation: CssAnimationBuilder;    // Animation CSS

  constructor(private _animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder,
     private _element: ElementRef, private service:MenuService) {
    this._animation = _animationBuilder.css();
    this.service.this.collapse$.subscribe((collapse) => {
      this.updateMenu(collapse);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.collapse) {
      this.updateMenu(changes.collapse);
    }
  }

  updateMenu(collapse:boolean) {
    if (this.collapse) {
        this.hide();
    } else {
        this.show();
    }
  }
}
```

The state can be updated from anywhere in your application using the `MenuService`. For example within a component without any relation with the menu:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div (click)="toggleMenu()">Toggle menu</div>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private service:MenuService) {
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.service.toggleMenu();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback ! It seems indeed preferable to put in place a MenuService as you said. I'll look into it and see what I can do with your advice thanks !
About ngDoCheck(), I first tried to do without, and with console.logs(), I witnessed the fact that my property was updating correctly on clicks, but the animation wasn't working. This is where I though my changes weren't detected and gave a try to ngDoCheck().
I'll keep working on it. Thanks again.