# Angular2 : Unclear behavior of property binding

Tags: angular

## Context

Hi, this question comes from the answer of my previous post :

[Angular2 : Error trying to diff 'true' with ngDoCheck()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987356/angular2-error-trying-to-diff-true-with-ngdocheck/37008184?noredirect=1#comment61592078_37008184)

**menuService.service.ts**

```
export class MenuService {
  collapse:boolean;
  collapse$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  toggleMenu() {
    this.collapse = !this.collapse;
    this.collapse$.next(this.collapse);
  }
}
```

The idea at first was to make a menu collapse with a property [collapse]. After the advices from the last question available in the link, I did put in place a service containing a boolean property for the state of the menu with an observable / subject to notify when it's updated.

**collapse.animation.ts**

```
export class Collapse {
    @Input() duration: number = 200;             
    @Input() collapse: any;                  
    private _animation: CssAnimationBuilder;

    constructor(animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder, private _element: ElementRef, private service: MenuService) {
        this._animation = animationBuilder.css();
        
        // Link to service
        this.service.collapse$.subscribe((collapse) => {
            this.updateMenu(collapse);
        });
    }

    updateMenu(collapse: boolean) {

        console.log("-----------------------");
        console.log("service.collapse : " + collapse);
        console.log("animation.collapse : " + this.collapse);
        console.log("-----------------------");

        // collapse from service or this.collapse from input ?
        if (collapse) {   
            this.hide();
        } else {
            this.show();
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

This class is my collapse css animation with the methods hide() and show(). When the "collapse" property gets updated, the html element linked to the property is then collapsed or not depending on the boolean value.

**header.component.html**

```
<button type="button" class="header_menu nav_icon root_navitem" id="btn_menu_switch" (click)="toggleMenu()">
    <img class="header_menu" src="css/App_Themes/VAL/48x48/m_bars.png" alt="" />
</button>

....

<div id="left_bar" tabindex="-1" class="left_bar collapse" [collapse]
     (clickOutside)="handleClickOutside( $event.target.className )">
</div>
```

This is the HTML template used in one of my components. The idea is that an image button is linked to the div menu to collapse :
My menu has the **[collapse]** property, which is linked to the Collapse animation. The button's **click()** event is linked to the service which updates the property value.

## Question

My issue is that I don't understand the relation between the collapse property on my html element, and my service property.
As you can see in the collapse.animation.ts file, I'm tracking the collapse values to see what's happening inside this piece of code.

When I run the application, the behavior of the menu is exactly as intended, but when I watch the logs, I see that :

```
-----------------------
service.collapse : false
animation.collapse : undefined
-----------------------
-----------------------
service.collapse : true
animation.collapse : undefined
-----------------------
....
```

And this is what I don't understand. If this.collapse is undefined, then I never need it, but at the same time I need to keep the @Input on my animation or my [collapse] defined on my Html will never get recognized.

As expected, if I delete the **@Input() collapse : any;** I get the following error message :

```
// EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
// Can't bind to 'collapse' since it isn't a known native property
```

So how does Angular2 makes the link between the service's collapse property and the HTML element's collapse property ? And why is animation.collapse undefined ?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is no relation. The `collapse` parameter is the one provided by the observer when calling its `next` method and `this.collapse` is a component property.

When the callback set in the subscribe method is called, `this.collapse` is updated if you do it explicitly:

```
updateMenu(collapse: boolean) {
  this.collapse = collapse;
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but then, why do I need the @Input() collapse :any; when it's actually undefined the whole time ? 
There is something I don't undestand...
To put it in another way : Is the @Input() necessary while it's never used in my animation directive ?

Comment: Or is it that I need the @Input() so my directive can understand what selector: '[collapse]' is and make the link ?

Comment: The input allows you to bind a property (component/directive) to an attribute. In your case, it's not clear that it's useful ;-)

Comment: Exactly, this is why it's so frustrating... I feel that I didn't make things correctly... and I don't see how I can make it clear.
How can I make it understand what [collapse] is without the @Input() ?

Comment: Because you don't provide the value of `collapse` as input of the component but through an observable ;-)